# Can I run ndk-gdb connected to two devices?

Tags: android-ndk, gdb, adb, ddms, ndk-gdb

I am trying to run two instances of ndk-gdb attached to two devices.

but based on this page, I can not find a way to do that...

https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/ndk-gdb.html

Is it even possible to have two separate devices connected to two instance of ndk-gdb running over adb?

Comment: have you tried -s option? it looks like it should work just like with adb